# Refresh page after only one click on submit

Tags: php, forms, submit

So I have the code bellow. My problem, is that to make the «vous êtes amis» message appear, the user have to click twice on the submit button. But I want to make the user click only once on the submit button. Thanks!

```
       <?php
       $checkcontact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE IDcontact = '".$dnn['id']."'");
       if(mysql_num_rows($checkcontact) == 1)
           {
           echo "<h1>Vous êtes amis</h1>";
           }
           else
           {
       ?>

<form method="post" action="profile.php?id=<?php echo $dnn['id']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$dnn['Username'];?>" name="userid" />
    <input type="submit" value="Add as Friend" />
</form>


<?php
if ($_POST)
{  
  $fid = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($_POST['userid']));
  $fid = mysql_real_escape_string($fid);
      include("base.php");
      mysql_query("INSERT into contacts (ID, Nom, IDcontact, Nomcontact) VALUES ('".$_SESSION  ['id']."', '".$_SESSION['Username']."', '".$dnn['id']."', '$fid')");
      }
}
?>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysql`. It is deprecated. Use prepared statements. Your query is dangerous. Learn about separation of concerns. You have markup and logic all mixed up and it's very hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move this block of code to the end:

```
  $checkcontact = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE IDcontact = '".$dnn['id']."'");
   if(mysql_num_rows($checkcontact) == 1)
       {
       echo "<h1>Vous êtes amis</h1>";
       }
       else
       {
```

This checks the value in the database AFTER it's been inserted. Right now, You're checking before it's been submitted

Comment: but now do you know how to make the submit button disapear? (after clicking on it)

Answer (score 0):

you must put your controller code **if ($_POST)...** before selecting data from database